# angularjs/ javascript - scroll left on an image not being applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have an image that is larger than its div, and the user is allowed to scroll left and right on the image. I am trying to center the image so the user see's the center of the image. I have tried adding scroll left

The view:

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;" ng-controller="ColorsCtrl">

    <div ng-show="!isLandscape">
        <div  style="overflow: scroll;" ng-if="isSelected(color.code)" ng-repeat="color in colors">
            <img id="fullSwatch" ng-src="{{ images.swatches_large[color.code] }}" full-swatch>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have a directive that manipulates the image of the picture to allow the scrolling.

```
colorsController.directive('fullSwatch', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('load', function() {

                var img = element[0];

                //swap width and height values because they are before orientation change
                var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
                var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);

                var imageWidth = img.width;
                var imageHeight = img.height;

                var aspectRatio = imageWidth / imageHeight;

                // fill image vertically
                imageHeight = h;
                imageWidth = h * aspectRatio;

                img.style.width = imageWidth + "px";
                img.style.height = imageHeight + "px";
                img.style.maxWidth = "none";

                // add scroll left to parent container to center image
                var container = img.parentNode();

                var scrollLeft = imageWidth / 2;
                container.scrollLeft = scrollLeft;

            });
        }
    };
});
```

The scroll left is not being applied, the image starts out all the way to the left.

Comment: The problem is simply this line `var container = img.parentNode();` Your console will show you the error that you've attempted to call a function that isn't a function. That should be `img.parentNode`. It is a property, not a function.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding overflow:auto; in the style tag something like this:
`<div style="overflow:auto;"></div>`
you can see the source code of my [quiz site](http://sqrt.in) for help

Comment: Link only answers are not permitted. Please include code and explanation of the solution.